# Populate new column added from check between columns from different Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a new column to a dataframe (**df_pgthsim**) containing the values from another column in another dataframe (**df_bn**) only if the value itself it is contained at the beginning of the string in the first dataframe.
If not, then it should insert False value (or '', Null, etc, but not the value itself)

Notice that I put the column of the **df_bn** dataframe in an array (**brandnames**) just to simplify the process.

I am trying with this:

```
for i, bn in enumerate(brandnames):
    print("Searching Brandname: ", bn)
    print("Index: ", i)
    
    df_pgthsim['brandname_poi'].iloc[i] = df_pgthsim['reference_name'].apply(lambda v: bn if v.startswith(bn) else False)

    print(df_pgthsim['brandname_poi'].unique())
```

This method throws my the following error:

> ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

So I´ve also tried this:

```
for bn in brandnames:
    print("Searching Brandname: ", bn)

    for i, val in df_pgthsim['reference_name'].items():

        df_pgthsim['brandname_poi'].iloc[i] = bn if val.startswith(bn) else False

    print(df_pgthsim['brandname_poi'].unique())
```

But it takes forever due to big amount of rows in both dataframes probably.

Is it any other way to do it having in mind the performance as well?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** Columns in both dataframes
[image: both_dataframes]

Comment: Please share a couple of rows of both dataframes, just the necessary columns and preferably with at least a couple of matching. thanks

Comment: @Ben.T I just edited the question with a picture of both dataframes with the columns that I want to compare to find a match (only if starts with the same substring) and if so, populate the new column with that value from 'df_branded_poi_data'

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html)

```
df_pgthsim['is_brand'] = df_pgthsim['bn'].str.startswith('bn')
```

This will create a column `is_brand` with `True` if strings in `bn` column starts with `bn` else False.

To populate with value, use `np.where`

```
df_pgthsim['brand'] = np.where(
    df_pgthsim['bn'].str.startswith('bn'),
    df_pgthsim['bn'],
    False     # or np.nan
)
```

Don't forget to import `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: But I need to populate it with the value itself not a True or False value

Comment: @FLBKernel Updated answer

Comment: I forgot to mention that the dataframes have different sizes so it cannot be done like this since it throws a ValueError: Length of values (100000) does not match length of index (9124)

Comment: There was a typo. Fixed it. @FLBKernel